# Vaadin demo animation : How to create similar animation

Tags: jquery, animation, vaadin, vaadin7

I am trying to build a client side application using Vaadin 7, and I found on their website ***[this](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#)*** animation.

Does anybody knows how to do such animation, or is there a code sample which I could refere to. I imagine JQuery is used too.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no code sample and jQuery is not used. The animation uses two concurrent CSS transitions rotating/scaling to opposite directions. It is non-trivial to get right and not all the browsers can do it at all (for those only scaling is used instead of rotation).

Comment: Thank you for your response @Joonas. I will look for how to do it.